# How can I define a function that takes a list of numbers and adds the first and last digits in Python 2.7?

Tags: python, python-2.7

This is what I tried:

```
def addFirstAndLast(x):
     return x[0] + x[-1]
```

Thought it would be as simple as that.

Comment: If this is a homework, please tag it as such.

Comment: "takes a list of numbers, and adds the first and last digits"?  Of all the numbers in the list?  Maybe you could clarify.  Also, you might want to figure out SO formatting, and what the comment character is in Python...

Comment: you could use `sizeof()` or `x.pop()` (if a list) for getting the last. Just some hints. As far as I see, your code is OK. Which one is the **error**?

Comment: @Kani: the `x[-1]` is fine, if `x` were an array of ints that correspond to decimal digits.

Answer (score 1):

The code you gave would work, if you converted your number into an array of (decimal) digits (converted from char to int).

E.g.

```
print addFirstAndLast([3, 1, 4, 1, 5])
```

should print 8. So all you now need to do, is convert your number into this array of ints corresponding to digits.

Comment: +1 addFirstAndLast([0,1]) would work fine... but not addFirstAndLast(["0","1"])

Answer (score 0):

If this is a list of number not the digits of numbers then I guess you have to convert numbers to digits first.

```
def add_first_and_last(input_list):
    result_list=list()
    for number in input_list:
        printed=str(number)
        result_list.append(printed[0]+printed[-1])
    return result_list
```

Answer (score 0):

```
    > def AddFirstAndLast(l1):
 if len(l1) == 0:
  return 0
 elif len(l1) == 1:
  return l1[0]
 else:
  return l1[0] + l1[-1]
```

This should work fine.... :)